# Is it possible to ignore the history for a directory in git without ignoring the files?

Tags: git

I have a directory in my application that contains compiled files (specifically in a rails app the public/assets folder which contains JS/CSS versions compiled from CoffeeScript/Sass files).

I don't want to ignore the directory completely, as I need the latest compiled versions to exist in the respositry, rather I would prefer if git didn't track all the changes to the files in the directory, as I don't want my git respository to be growing constantly with file history I don't care about.

Is this possible at all? Am I crazy for wanting to do this?

Comment: Why commit the compiled files instead of compiling them from source?

Comment: @Useless for heroku: I want to precompile the assets before I push them up to heroku, and the only way to push to heroku is via git. Currently I fork to a deploy branch, compile and commit in there, force push to heroku, then delete the local deploy branch. But the constant force push dance is annoying and scary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're crazy to version compiled objects at all IMO, but it seems like Heroku is crazy too.

That being the case, I'd wrap the deployment process in a script to:

1. branch
2. compile
3. commit the compiled assets (ick)
4. force push
5. reset the local branch HEAD so you keep the branch point as a tag, but the orphaned commit with the compiled assets can be garbage collected
6. switch back to the original branch

Note that you'll still be able to checkout the branch and roll it forward again to the deployed commit at any time before GC clears it out so long as you provide some way to track it (a note with the commit SHA would work), and if you're too late you can still reproduce the build from source.

---

OK, so this obviously fails if you have multiple repos. I can't see a way to fix this, but you *could* have a single master/deployment repo running something like a CI environment.

Do a regular (un-forced) push of source only to the master deployment repo, and have it do the branch/compile/deploy/discard steps automatically. If you want to use the master repo for syncing changes between your working environments without always deploying, you could have it run the deployment sequence only when a tag is pushed, for example.

Comment: Yeah that's almost exactly what I do now. The force push has caught me out on the odd occasion working from multiple machines and forgetting to check that my local repo is up to date.